# Преобразовать массив, увеличив каждую его серию на один элемент

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Преобразовать массив, увеличив каждую его серию на один элемент. 
(серия это подряд идущие одинаковые элементы)
например если  a=[1,1,2,3,2,2] то получится a=[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,2]

```
        <script>
        a=[1,1,2,3,2,2]
        n=a.length;
        temp=0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (a[i+1]==a[i]){
            temp++;
        }
    }
    for (i=n+temp;i>=0;i--){
          if(a[i-1]!=a[i]){
             a[i+1] = a[i];
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: А что конкретно не работает в вашем коде? Или он полностью не рабочий и вы просто хотите, чтобы задачу решили за вас?

Comment: `a=[1,1,2,3,2,2];     
      temp=a[0];       
    result=[temp];  
    for (i=1;i<a.length;i++){
          if(a[i]!=temp){
          result.push(temp)
          temp=a[i];
         }
        result.push(temp)
        }    
         result.push(temp)   `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку речь о JavaScript, можно воспользоваться методом splice и тем фактом, что JS позволяет обращаться к элементам за границами массива:

```
var a = [1,1,2,3,2,2];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] != a[i+1]) {
        a.splice(i, 0, a[i])
        i++;
    }
}
```

В более строгих языках код был бы немного сложнее.